# Test exceptions in jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a new `Array.prototype` method

```
// tslint:disable-next-line: interface-name
interface Array<T> {
    random(): T;
    randomInRange(): T;
}

Array.prototype.random = function random() {
    if (this.length < 3) {
        throw new Error();
    }
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
```

How do I write test case to verify if an error is thrown?

```
// prototypes.test.ts
import './prototypes';

describe('Test Array.prototype.random method', () => {
    it('should return a random number from the array', () => {
        const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        const random = arr.random();
        const isNumberPresentInArray = arr.includes(random);

        expect(isNumberPresentInArray).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should throw error if there are less than 3 elements in the array', () => {
        const arr = [1, 2];
        expect(arr.random()).toThrow(new Error());
    });
});
```

I tried with `toThrowError` as well, but no luck.

Comment: You need to pass a callable that errors on invocation, otherwise the error occurs *before* you actually call `expect`. Read [the example](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) more carefully: *"Note: **You must wrap the code in a function**, otherwise the error will not be caught and the assertion will fail"* (emphasis mine).

Comment: you mean `expect(() => arr.random())` or something like this?